# SweetAlert2 click confirm while testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist, sweetalert

I'm trying to click the sweetalert popup in my rails tests but it keeps telling me that it cannot find the button. My code looks like this:

```
it "should delete dummy user", js: true do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  login user
  FactoryGirl.create(:course, :with_user_created)
  dummy_user = FactoryGirl.create(:dummy_user)
  visit booking_index_path("en")
  current_path.should eq(booking_index_path("en"))
  page.should have_content(dummy_user.name)
  page.find("#delete_dummy_" + dummy_user.id.to_s).trigger("click")
  click_button "Yes"
  page.should have_no_content(dummy_user.name)
end
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find button "Yes"
```

I'm calling sweetalert like so:

```
var modal_open = false;

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".alert-sweet").on('click', function(e){
    if (modal_open){
      modal_open = false;
      return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    link = $(this);
    swal({
      title: "<%= t("you_sure") %>",
      confirmButtonText: "<%= t("t_yes") %>",
      cancelButtonText: "<%= t("t_no") %>",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton : true,
      confirmButtonColor : "#DD6B55",
      closeOnConfirm : false
    }).then(function() {
      modal_open = true;
      link.trigger('click');
    }, function(dismiss) {
      if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
        modal_open = false;
      }
    });
      return false;
  });
});
```

Any idea why Capybara cannot find the button? I've tried to print the hole page after click "#delete_dummy_" + dummy_user.id.to_s" and it seems that the button is there:

```
...
<div class="swal2-container">
  <div class="swal2-overlay" tabindex="-1"></div>
      <div class="swal2-modal" style="display: none; width: 500px; padding: 20px; margin-left: -250px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="swal2-icon swal2-error" style="display: none;">
            <span class="x-mark">
                <span class="line left"></span>
                <span class="line right"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="swal2-icon swal2-question" style="display: none;">?</div>
        <div class="swal2-icon swal2-warning pulse-warning" style="display: block;">!</div>
        <div class="swal2-icon swal2-info" style="display: none;">i</div>
        <div class="swal2-icon swal2-success" style="display: none;">
            <span class="line tip"></span> 
            <span class="line long"></span>
            <div class="placeholder"></div> 
            <div class="fix"></div>
        </div>
        <img class="swal2-image" style="display: none;">
        <h2>Are you sure?</h2>
        <div class="swal2-content" style="display: none;"></div>
        <input class="swal2-input">
        <select class="swal2-select"></select>
        <div class="swal2-radio"></div>
        <label for="swal2-checkbox" class="swal2-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="swal2-checkbox"></label>
        <textarea class="swal2-textarea"></textarea>
        <div class="swal2-validationerror"></div>
        <hr class="swal2-spacer" style="display: block;">
        <button class="swal2-confirm styled" style="background-color: rgb(221, 107, 85);">Yes</button>
        <button class="swal2-cancel styled" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);">No</button>
        <span class="swal2-close" style="display: none;">×</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Looks like the problem is because sweetalert is not visible. I already disabled the animations but still it's not turning it visible on clicking. Any suggestions?

Comment: save a screenshot after clicking the delete_dummy_... element and see what is actually on the page - as an aside, you really shouldn't be using the `eq` matcher with current_path it can easily lead to flaky tests - instead do `page.should have_current_path(booking_index_path("en"))`

Comment: Looking at the sweetalert project page, it doesn't seem to mention anywhere that swal returns a promise, so calling `.then` on it may not be valid -- does your poltergeist driver config have `js_errors: false` set so you're hiding JS errors occurring on your page?

Answer (score 0):

Try to `sleep`:

```
page.find("#delete_dummy_" + dummy_user.id.to_s).trigger("click")
sleep(1)
click_button "Yes"
```

Comment: @InesM try to debug by adding `gem pry-rails` and set breakpoint `binding.pry` instead of `sleep(1)`. It will stop execution and show the browser at the moment, then you'll be able to interact with it

Comment: @itsnikolay According to the tags poltergeist is being used, so it's not going to show a browser

Comment: @InesM if you use `poltergeist` driver, try: `find_button("Yes").trigger('click')`

Comment: I think the problem is that the SweetAlert pop up is not visible, so it cannot find the button. I disabled the animations but still the button isn't visible.